# Ruby - How do I shorten my method

Tags: ruby

I have a hash here:

```
VALID_CHOICES = {
  'r' => 'rock',
  'p' => 'paper',
  'sc' => 'scissors',
  'l' => 'lizard',
  'sp' => 'spock'
}
```

And a method which basically compares here:

```
def win?(first, second)
  (first == 'sc' && second == 'p') ||
    (first == 'p' && second == 'r') ||
    (first == 'r' && second == 'l') ||
    (first == 'l' && second == 'sp') ||
    (first == 'sp' && second == 'sc') ||
    (first == 'sc' && second == 'l') ||
    (first == 'l' && second == 'p') ||
    (first == 'p' && second == 'sp') ||
    (first == 'sp' && second == 'r') ||
    (first == 'r' && second == 'sc')
end
```

How can I rewrite my method in very short concise code that means exactly the same thing? Any idea? Is it possible to do it using hashes?

Comment: This belongs to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: One method would be to use a Set (either a proper set or hash-with-ignored-values) using keys `[f,s]`. Then if the key for the combination exists it is a "win".

Comment: How? Can you show me?

Comment: What @user2864740 means, I think, is that the set could contain the 10 pairs of arrays implied by your `win?` method: `[sc,p]`, `[p,r]` and so on. An ordered pair would be a win if the corresponding two-element array is in the set. Set look-ups are much faster than evaluating an `if` statement or stepping through an array (which is not surprising as sets are implemented with hashes under the covers). Using sets might be faster than what you have, but the amount of code required would in fact be greater.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should define clear rules for what each token can win:

```
WINS = {
  'r' => %w{l sc},
  'p' => %w{r sp},  
  'sc' => %w{p l},
  'l' => %w{p sp},
  'sp' => %w{r sc}
}
```

Now you can determine wins using a simple lookup:

```
def win?(first, second)
  WINS[first].include?(second)
end
```

While there may be several 'clever' ways to avoid an explicit structure like `WINS`, explicit rules are much more understandable - and therefore, more maintainable.  Conciseness in code is considered a positive attribute where it improves the readability of the code.  Conciseness to the extreme that causes the code to be difficult to understand is *not* something to strive for.

Comment: Good answer, but I doubt that there are any "clever ways" here. With RPS, yes, but there's no cyclic structure to exploit in this expanded version. It's curious that there are only "wins" in this game. With RPS the point is generally to determine which of three outcomes applies: A wins, B wins, a tie (when A and B make the same selection).

Comment: @JohnCarter: given a `first`, you fetch moves that can be beaten by it. If `second` is one of those, it's a win.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `(a.index(first) - a.index(second)).modulo(5).odd?` with an array `a = %w[r p sc sp l]` would be a "clever" way, but no one wants to maintain such code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [user2864740's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460707/ruby-how-do-i-shortened-my-method#comment66242552_39460707) and [Cary Swoveland's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460707/ruby-how-do-i-shortened-my-method#comment66243317_39460707), you could also use a hash to map "winning pairs" to their respective verb:

```
WINS = {
  %w[scissors paper]    => 'cuts',
  %w[paper    rock]     => 'covers',
  %w[rock     lizard]   => 'crushes',
  %w[lizard   spock]    => 'poisons',
  %w[spock    scissors] => 'smashes',
  %w[scissors lizard]   => 'decapitates',
  %w[lizard   paper]    => 'eats',
  %w[paper    spock]    => 'disproves',
  %w[spock    rock]     => 'vaporizes',
  %w[rock     scissors] => 'crushes'
}
```

It returns the corresponding verb if the key's first item beats the second:

```
WINS[['paper', 'rock']] #=> "covers"
```

and `nil` if it doesn't:

```
WINS[['rock', 'paper']] #=> nil
```

In your method:

```
def win?(first, second)
  WINS.has_key?([first, second])
end
```

Or to check both sides:

```
if WINS.has_key?([first, second])
  # first wins
elsif WINS.has_key?([second, first])
  # second wins
else
  # tie
end
```

Or more verbose:

```
def result(first, second)
  if verb = WINS[[first, second]]
    "first wins: #{first} #{verb} #{second}" 
  elsif verb = WINS[[second, first]]
    "second wins: #{second} #{verb} #{first}" 
  else
    "tie"
  end
end

result('rock', 'scissors')
#=> "first wins: rock crushes scissors"

result('spock', 'lizard')
#=> "second wins: lizard poisons spock"

result('paper', 'paper')
#=> "tie"
```

Of course, you can also use your abbreviations (`sc`, `p`, `r`, `l`, `sp`) instead of whole words.